# Where is the connection manager in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 but I can't find a connection manager. I want to add a connection manually. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Don't you see the "Add" button?

Comment: ^^ To previous comment... Looks like screenshot from previous version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @walidwithu are you using Unity as Desktop Environment in 18.10 instead of Default Gnome D.E?

Answer (score 0):

Try run in command-line:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

**OR**

To install NetworkManager:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

To install the GNOME applet / indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Start network manager

```
sudo start network-manager
```